# Use join fetch by default with Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a simple schema "Posts have messages that have users" and I want get messages with User data.

```
@Entity
class User {
   @Id
   var id: Int = 0
   var name: String = ""
   var usenrame: String = ""
}


@Entity
class Messages {
  @Id
  var id: Int = 0

  var text: String = ""

  @ManyToOne()
  var user = User()

}


class Post {
  var id: Int = 0

  @OneToMany()
  @JoinColum()
  var messsages: List<Messages> = ArrayList()
}
```

This works, but, Spring Data / Hibernate, instead of create a single query with join to get message and user, use two queries

I can use a custom repository method to get directly a message and it works fine

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Message m LEFT JOIN FECTH m.user WHERE id =:id")
fun findMessageById(id: Int)
```

But... I don't get any way to get a Post with all messages and users...

I understand that each Post need a query to get all messages, but, I want that query get too user and not get another query for each message to get the user...

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not quite understand: Under which cirumstances does Spring Data issue two queries to the DB? And: Is class `Post` related to your question? I do not see the connection.

Comment: I want get posts like:

val posts = postRepository.findAll()


This should do a query for get post, for each post a query for get message and user.

With 5 post, it should do 6 queries

But now, it make a query for post, other for each post for get the messages a other for each message to get the user...

So, for 5 post with 5 messages it do 26 queries

Comment: I think that _one query_ would be enough to fetch this. But with JPA we all get quite modest in our expectations to database performance. My guess here is that since `Message` has a `@ManyToOne` relation to `User`, Hibernate may try to _limit_ the requests to the `USER` table in case every message has the same user.

Comment: BTW, but probably unrelated: I’m not so fond of that `var user = User()` in `Message`. I model my entities with constructors like this: `@Entity class Messages(@Id var id: Int, var text: String, @ManyToOne var user)`